# PHP Regular Expression pull out <select>'s option value

Tags: php, regex

I want to use Regular Expression to pull out `<select>` option values,but failed.

This is my code:

```
preg_match_all('/value=[\"\']([^\"\' ]+)/i', $content, $value);
```

Comment: by "general expression" do you mean "regex"?

Comment: DOM is the past way to parse a web page or part of one.

Comment: @Dagon, no, I won't use DOM because low speed and memory leak for my case ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following preg_replace matches the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag and returns its contents via `$1`.

`$gotcha = preg_replace(/<option\s.*?value="(.+?)"/i, $1, $source);`

And you can also use the regex above in `preg_match_all()` to get an array of matches:

Note that, because you're dealing with an indeterminate number of characters between `<option` and `value="`, you can't use lookbehind to extract only the goodies from a string with the necessary prerequisites. This means that you'll have to use a replacement function and backreferences to isolate the value for each tag.

Comment: thanks @Aaron,I finally get it work by myself.  preg_match_all('/value=[\"\']([^\"\' ]+)/i', $content, $value); I will try your method too.

Comment: That regex will be fine as long as you're not expecting it to weed out other `input` elements with a `value` attribute.